# Register new media codec in FMX media player in C++ Builder

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

When I try to play an `.mp4` video file using the `TMediaPlayer` FMX control in C++Builder, it reports an error:

> unsupported media file

So, I tried to register an MP4 codec in FMX's Media Codec Manager using the below code:

```cpp
TMediaCodecManager::RegisterMediaCodecClass(".mp4", "mp4", TMediaType::Video, TWindowsMediaCodec);
```

But it also reporte an error:

> TWindowsMediaCodec is undefined symbol

How do I register a new codec in FMX's Media Player in C++Builder?

Comment: Do you have `#include <FMX.Media.Win.hpp>` in your code?  As long as your project links to the `FMX.Media` unit, that will link to the `FMX.Media.Win` unit for you when compiling for Windows, and the `FMX.Media.Win` unit already registers `TWindowsMediaCodec` for several formats, including MP4.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. Did you mean I don't need to register new codec by myself? But it reports `Undefined symbol IDirectShowStream` in file `Winapi.DirectShow9.hpp`.

Comment: "*Did you mean I don't need to register new codec by myself?*" - yes, it should already be automatic. "*But it reports `Undefined symbol IDirectShowStream` in file `Winapi.DirectShow9.hpp`*" - that is a separate issue. On Windows, the media player uses the DirectShow API, and there is no `IDirectShowStream` in that API (that I can find). Where are you seeing `IDirectShowStream` being used?

Comment: I didn't use `IDirectShowStream` directly. I just have a basic `TMediaPlayer` and that's it. Should I just update the Windows SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the K_Lite_Codec-Pack_1612. I am using the Standard Pack but any of the three variants will do the trick.